# How to expand a div to fit remaining viewport space but prevent a child element from expanding its size anymore?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Wirefram]

As the wireframe indicates, I want the div to take up the remaining space of the viewport BUT not be expandable.

The issue I have is that I am rendering a canvas inside the div of say 800x1000px – I want it to scale accordingly to fit the div but instead, what is happening is that I am getting a vertical scroll on the div.

I have used `flexGrow: 1` to expand the div but that doesn't solve the second issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Provide some code so we can help you

Comment: height: 100% maybe. But yeah provide the code you have written yet

Comment: Well, this is a conceptual bug right now so I haven't been able to implement anything that works. But, I'll make a jsfiddle real quick to better explain my query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created an example that does what you want. The blue element is the canvas. If you want something different, please tell me and also if you can, provide some code. It works correctly on Chrome, Edge, Firefox and Safari 14.0.3 (credits to @Christos Lytras)

```css
body, div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#navbar {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

#container {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  display: flex;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 70px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#main {
  flex: 1;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex; /*in order to work on Firefox*/
  background-color: #3939ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar"></div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <div id="main">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```